# How to manipulate specific cell in Laravel-excel?

Tags: php, laravel-6, laravel-excel

Tried searching for it in the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/) for version 3.1. It exists in version 2.1 but I can't seem to find this feature even in google.